# Debug.WriteLine in release build

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

Is there a way to use `Debug.WriteLine` in a release build without defining `DEBUG`?

Comment: Definining _DEBUG in the release build has far fewer side effects than you may fear.  Certainly don't hesitate to define it when troubleshooting a release build problem.

Comment: Use [.NET Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6s4h68(v=vs.110).aspx) (preferably TraceSources). It's *much* more flexible.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

No, but you can use the `Trace` in release by defining `TRACE` and using `Trace.WriteLine.` Have a look here:

> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815788/how-to-trace-and-debug-in-visual-c

Comment: Perfect. I just want to use SysInternals DebugViewer and Trace.WriteLine seems to get picked up by it

Answer (score 50):

No. If you don't define the `DEBUG` preprocessor symbol, any calls to `Debug.*` will be removed by the compiler due to the `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` attribute being applied.

You might want to consider [`Trace.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.writeline.aspx) or other logging techniques though.

Answer (score 22):

While you still have to define DEBUG - you don't have to do it assembly wide. You can define it only in the source files that you want. So if you want debug logging from a particular class you can define DEBUG just for that source file.

```
#define DEBUG
using System.Diagnostics;

...

class Logger
{
    void Log( string msg ){ Debug.WriteLine( msg ); }
}
```

Comment: I like this method the best. The #define only applies to the source file and not the whole project. This is a good way to release a library in a nuget (say) that can be reused by other projects when they are in DEBUG mode for doing Debug.Writeline with custom outcomes likes timestamps and exception handling, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can, as mentioned in the above comments use TRACE, or without defining any compile time constants, by using Expression Trees.

```
        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "text");
        var callExp =
            Expression.Call(
              typeof(System.Diagnostics.Debug).GetRuntimeMethod(
                   "WriteLine", new [] { typeof(string) }),
              p);
        Action<string> compiledAction = Expression.Lambda<Action<string>>(
                                         callExp, p)
                                         .Compile();
```

After this, you can invoke the Debug.WriteLine anytime, by calling

```
        compiledAction("Debug text");
```

You're essentially tricking the compiler by not having a static method call, but instead dynamically constructing it at run-time.

There is no performance-hit since, the action is compiled and re-used.

This is how I wrote a DebugLogger in SharpLog.

> You may take a look at the source code here, if it interests you: https://github.com/prasannavl/SharpLog/blob/master/SharpLog/DebugLogger.cs

Comment: I don't know if I'd ever recommend this .. but it's an "interesting" solution.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, in general. But if the production code, is anyway going to print out the debug values, then it makes no difference if its `Debug.WriteLine` or the compiled Lambda, which is **almost** just a `(() => Debug.WriteLine())` without the JIT optimizations in play.

Answer (score 1):

`Debugger.Log(0, null, "Your string here");` could be an alternative, it is used internally by `Debug.Write` and it also works in Release.