# How to ouput API debug logs in a file ? (IIS)

Tags: asp.net, logging, iis, azure-application-insights

I have an issue with an app (api) using application insights.
On my computer, everything is fine.
On the dev server, nothing happens.
The application insights output on visual studio is very self explanatory. If I can get hold to them, I will be able to investigate.

How do you output the "output debug" like in visual studio in a file when hosted on IIS ?

Comment: Do you have the App Insights IIS agent installed on the dev server? There is some telemetry that App Insights can't collect from .NET Framework apps without the module. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/status-monitor-v2-overview

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT The thing is the basic telemetry is collected when on a dev computer (like which page is accessed, etc...). Right now, nothing is sent.

Answer (score 0):

In order to capture the `Debug.Write` and `Debug.Writeline` outputs, We could use the `DebugView` from `sysinternal`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview
DebugView is an application that lets you monitor debug output on your local system.
Besides, Response.AppendTolog(), a built-in method, also can write IIS log files.
[write to IIS log from an ASP.NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135028/write-to-iis-log-from-an-asp-net-application)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(...) and you see output in Visual Studio.
and enable debug in [webconfig](https://github.com/microsoft/msdn-content/blob/master/msdn-lib/How-to-Enable-Debugging-for-ASP-NET-Applications.md)